# Length of $A/\mathfrak{m}^2$ as an $A$-module

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, solution-verification

Let $A$ be a commutative noetherian ring and $\mathfrak{m}\subset A$ a maximal ideal generated by $1$ element $f\in A$.

In that case, $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2=\langle\overline{f}\rangle_A$ and $\ell(\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2)=1$. Now consider the exact sequence of $A$-modules:
$$0\to \mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2\to A/\mathfrak{m}^2\to A/\mathfrak{m}\to 0$$
That way $\ell(A/\mathfrak{m}^2)=\ell(\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2)+\ell(A/\mathfrak{m})=1+1=2$.

I'm trying to find out whether or not this argument works in general for $n$ generators $f_1,...,f_n$.

If $f_1,...,f_n$ is a minimal set of generators of $\mathfrak{m}$, then $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2=\langle\overline{f_1},...,\overline{f_n}\rangle_A$ and I'm tempted to say that $\ell(\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2)=n$, so that $\ell(A/\mathfrak{m}^2)=n+1$.

But I don't know how to prove that $\overline{f_1},...,\overline{f_n}$ is a minimal set of generators for $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$, and I don't even know if this is true in general.

Maybe some additional hypothesis on $A$ or $\mathfrak{m}$ are necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may assume $A$ is local with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, since localizing at $\mathfrak{m}$ does not change $A/\mathfrak{m}^2$.  By Nakayama's lemma, then, if $M$ is a finitely generated $A$-module and elements $m_1,\dots,m_k$ are such that their images in $M/\mathfrak{m}M$ generate $M/\mathfrak{m}M$, then they generate $M$.  So, if $m_1,\dots,m_k$ are a minimal set of generators for $M$, their images much be a minimal set of generators for $M/\mathfrak{m}M$, since no proper subset can generate.  Applying this to $M=\mathfrak{m}$ gives you what you want.

Comment: In order to use Nakayama lemma don't we need $A$ to be local?

Comment: Oh, I missed that it wasn't.  But it doesn't matter, since all the modules you're dealing with are actually $A_\mathfrak{m}$-modules anyways.